# Remove the image slider in product detail page

Tags: product, product-images, product-view, page-layouts

I want to to remove the slider in images

[image: Current]

**What I want it to be like :**

[image: Design what I want]

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to display Image slider then you need to remove the default product image gallery (fotorama gallery widget).

And as per your screenshot provided you need image one by one, then **you need to create one custom product attribute with wysiwyg editor**, in which you have to insert multiple images in backend and you need to fetch this custom attribute on frontend.